# Export GLTF with two base color textures (Making a smooth transition between two textures)

Tags: materials, node-editor, export, gltf

I have been trying to make a smooth transition between two textures in Blender, the goal is to not have a huge 8k texture for my ground, but instead two small textures that I "paint" the ground with in order to make a path. I tried many different things but I can't get anything to work, when I export to GLTF, only one texture gets exported.

It could be a "hack" or anything I don't mind, it is going to be used in Three.js

Here is my node editor and the render on top which is fine until I export to GLTF:
[image]

Comment: You won't be able to export that to glTF. The best thing to do is probably to replace the material with one that does what you want after importing on the Three.js side.

Comment: How can I do that using Three.js please

Comment: Dunno, you should probably ask on a Three.js forum or something.

Comment: I found the answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880715/texture-splatting-with-three-js